# Linking RVCT libraries with GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, static-linking

I am trying to link a static third party library compiled with `RVCT 2.2` with a test program compiled with `GCC` (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41).

If I link with `-static`, everything works as it should. If I do not use `-static` however, I get lots of complaints like the following:

```
foolib.a(foo.o): In function `foofunc':
foo.c:(.text+0x4c8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_memcpy'
foolib.a(bar.o): In function `barfunc':
bar.c:(.text+0xa54): undefined reference to `__aeabi_memclr4'
```

Both `memcpy` and `memset` should be present in libc. 
Clearly `GCC` can somehow detect and fix this if I use `-static`. Can someone explain what is happening? I assume that `GCC` dynamically links to libc unless I add the `-static` flag, but shouldn't `__aeabi_memcpy` and similar be defined in the shared libc library as well?

EDIT:
In order to let people test this themselves I have now created a minimalistic test case like follows:

```
//foo.c
#include <string.h>

void foo(void *dst, void *src, int num) {
    memcpy(dst, src, num);
}
```

This file is compiled and archived with RVCT 2.2 as follows:

```
armcc.exe --arm -c --apcs=/noswst/interwork foo.c -o foo.o
armar.exe --create foo.a foo.o
```

This library is then linked with the following test program:

```
//bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern void foo(void *dst, void *src, int num);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[10], b[10], i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            a[i] = i;
    }

    foo(b, a, sizeof(a));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (a[i] != b[i]) {
                    printf("Diff at %d: %d != %d\n", i, a[i], b[i]);
                    return 1;
            }
    }
    printf("Success!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Using the following command:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall bar.c foo.a -o bar
```

Which gives the following output (unless `-static` is also used):

```
foo.a(foo.o): In function `foo':
foo.c:(.text+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_memcpy'
arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: bar: hidden symbol `__aeabi_memcpy' isn't defined
arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The binary foo.a can be downloaded from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14498565/foo.a in case you don't have RVCT.

Comment: Was the toolchain compiled with support for shared libraries?  I remember seeing an issue myself one time, and we weren't compiling the toolchain with support for shared libraries.

Comment: Not sure, it is the pre-compiled binary supplied on the CodeSourcery website. I can create shared libraries with it though so I think it has support for it.

Comment: Are you using something like -nodefaultlibs?  If so, you might need to manually link against libgcc_s.

Comment: This article says arm compiler can link memcpy to a special optimized one.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3934.html

Comment: @jszakmeister Nope, I compile with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -O2 testprog.c library.a -o testprog`, plus `-static` to get it to work.

Comment: What happens if you do the final link step with armlink rather than ld?

Comment: @PeteFordham: If I use armlink, the linking works without complaints, but the executable does not work on the target device since armlink will use the RVCT standard libraries which are not present on the device.

Comment: Does adding `-v` give any insight: `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v -Wall bar.c foo.a -o bar`?  Also what version of gcc is this?  And which libc is your arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc using?  I imagine glibc, but want to double check.

Comment: @jszakmeister: Adding -v does not really tell me anything more. The arguments to collect2 are slightly different when adding -static but nothing I can pinpoint. I've tried both CodeSourcery's compiler (version is in the first paragraph) and arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc which comes with the gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc package in Ubuntu. Same results for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some time with this @Leo, I think I understand what's going on.  It appears that foo.o was compiled in a way that expects a *static* link to `__aeabi_memcpy`.  Looking at foo.o with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump -t`, I see this:

```
foo.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 foo.c
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l       *ABS*  00000000 BuildAttributes$$THUMB_ISAv1$ARM_ISAv4$M$PE$A:L22$X:L11$S22$IEEE1$IW$USESV6$~STKCKD$USESV7$~SHL$OSPACE$EBA8$REQ8$PRES8$EABIv2
00000000 l     O .debug_frame$$$.text   00000000 C$debug_frame$$$.text7
00000000  w    F *UND*  00000000 .hidden Lib$$Request$$armlib
00000000       F *UND*  00000000 .hidden __aeabi_memcpy
00000000 g     F .text  00000004 .hidden foo
```

Note the `-t` in the command line... that's for showing us the static symbols (non-shared).  Running `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump -T` on foo.o shows this:

```
foo.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

/home/jszakmeister/.local/sourcery-arm-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump: foo.o: not a dynamic object
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

So `__aeabi_memcpy` is looking to be resolved via a static link, which is why using `-static` works.  I believe if you compiled foo.o a little differently, so that it expects a shared C library, then you could link to foo.a without specifying -static.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the RVCT compiler, or I'd tell you how.

FWIW, using `strace` I was able to see that it is indeed linking against the shared C library, but not resolving the link.  I also used the `--sysroot=/path/to/code/sourcery/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc` command line option to make sure it was finding the correct C library.

Comment: Great! This does indeed seem to explain what is happening. I will have to investigate the RVCT compiler flags then I guess.

Answer (score 0):

These are helper functions defined by the runtime ABI:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0043c/IHI0043C_rtabi.pdf

A workaround for this could be to implement your own versions of these (using the libc memcpy and memset), but it may also be that there are more subtle linking issues going on here that could trip you up further on. Difficult to say without access to the object files.

Comment: The strange thing is that GCC seems to fix this itself if supplied with `-static`. I have now added example code and object files in case you want to experiment.